# Why does my OpenFileDialog doesn't show images in C#?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Here is my code:

```
var setImageDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
setImageDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|.jpg";
setImageDialog.ShowDialog();
```

But the dialog itself doesn't show the image in the folder I am in. For example, on my desktop, I have one `jpg` image, but it is not showing on the dialog.

I tried also to add `jpeg` to the list but still doesn't work:

```
setImageDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpeg, *.jpg)|.jpeg;.jpg";
```

The file name is: `C:\Users\michael\Desktop\CENTRAL_1024_ynet_logo.jpg`

Comment: Show us how you tried to add *.jpeg. Also show us the real name of the file.

Comment: Windows by default hides known filename extensions.  So the file might be named CENTRAL_1024_ynet_logo.jpg.png :)  Be sure to put Explorer into programmer mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

`setImageDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";`

Notice you forgot an asterisk